# Discord.py (table user has 1 columns but 6 values were supplied)

Tags: sqlite3, discord.py

Вылазит ошибка во время запуска кода. Пытался поставить (?,?,?,?,?,?), ({member.id}', '{member}', 0, 0, 1, 0) - Не помогло. Убирал ссылку на файл подключения - Не помогло.
Перепробывал уже много способ, всё напрасно, может кто нибудь сталкивался, и сможет помочь?

```
connect=sqlite3.connect('discord.db')
cursor=connect.cursor()


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
        "id" INT,
        "name" TEXT,
        "cash" BIGINT,
        "lvl" INT,
        "rank" INT,
        "runes" INT
    )""")
    connect.commit()
    print('Bot Ready')

    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM user WHERE id={member.id}").fetchone() == None:
                cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO user VALUES('{member.id}', '{member}', 0, 0, 1, 0)")
                connect.commit()
            else:
                pass
            connect.commit()
```

Сама ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\APython\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\APython\Code\DforriaMG\main.py", line 28, in on_ready
    cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO user VALUES('{member.id}', '{member}', 0, 0, 1, 0)")
sqlite3.OperationalError: table user has 1 columns but 6 values were supplied
```

Answer (score 0):

В строке:

```
cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO user VALUES('{member.id}', '{member}', 0, 0, 1, 0)")
```

Колонка `id` у вас типа `int`, значит вводить нужно `int`, а вы ставите скобки, тем самым вставляете значение как строку.

```
cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO user VALUES({member.id}, '{member}', 0, 0, 1, 0)")
```